# How to use volley library to pass the parameters to web service and get json array response?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

In my app, I am using volley library to fetch json data. 
Below is my code to pass the parameters to web service:

```
private void getProductName(final String id) {

    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
    pDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    showDialog();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.DARSHAN_URL+Constants.PRODUCT_NAME,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                            String material_id = person.getString("material_id");
                            String material_desc = person.getString("material_desc");

                            HashMap<String, String> maim_category_array = new HashMap<>();

                            maim_category_array.put("material_id", material_id);
                            maim_category_array.put("material_desc", material_desc);

                            productName.add(maim_category_array);

                        }

                        adapter = new GridviewAdapter(ProductNameActivity.this, productName);
                        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>)arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

                                Toast.makeText(ProductNameActivity.this,  map.get("material_id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent i = new Intent(ProductNameActivity.this, SubProductActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("BREADCRUMB1",  map.get("material_desc"));
                                i.putExtra("MATERIAL_ID",  map.get("material_id"));
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                        // txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    hideDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("material_id", id);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    DarshanApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

I am passing the material_id to the url. But getting response as **com.android.volley.servererror**

How to resolve the issue??
**please help!!**

Comment: doesn't `servererror` means that there is a server error? And also which exactly servererror is it? which error code and message?

Comment: after debugging the code I am getting the error only as error: com.android.volley.servererror. error message is empty.

Comment: @Sweekar Check the error response received. That will tell you where it went wrong. Use tools like advance rest client to check your parameters

Comment: I have doubt about the code. Is it correct to pass parameters and get json array response?

Comment: Try looking at the network response object in the `VolleyError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use volley but there is another way too. I use build in java and android methods to fetch JSON and display them.
You can take a look here

```
»JsonFetch
```

Comment: I have problem with sending parameters to web service method. Not with the fetching json.

Comment: Oh !.You can post to server also with same method . you just have to make request method to post .